# Backup app like Macrium for mac

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a app that can backup a Mac system to an image file, like Macrium that does a sector to sector backup, including the system files and doesn't start complaining about OS versions and other trash.

Comment: Disk utility (using its helper tool `asr`) makes block by block clones of a drive to image files. Are there other requirements why you’re not using the OS delivered tools for this?

Comment: Yes, more information about what you're trying to achieve would be helpful. What do you mean by "doesn't complain about OS versions"? Sectors on an SSD aren't really the same as on a hard drive. A typical Mac internal drive has several different volumes and other file-format structures. There's usually on need to backup the OS: only the Data volume.

Comment: My bad, yes I'm trying to turn an USB installer of el capitan made in Mac, backed up to an image so it can be flashed on any USB to make it install ready, instead of using a mac every time. The same with cloning a mac with catalina on it for example, I'm looking for something that can clone it like Macrium does for Windows so it can be deployed to other macs without a hassle. Disk utility only backs up files and doesn't make bootable copies anymore if my intelligence is current.